How do I determine what characters grant Vault tokens in Marvel Puzzle Quest when used?
Today while playing Marvel Puzzle Quest, I happen to use Magneto (3 star), and after winning, I got a pop-up that said I got a Vault token for using him.
In the past, I've gotten different Vault tokens for using X character, but I've never been able to determine how a user is supposed to know this, but figure there has to be. Using the Deadpool (5 star) grants a vault token every day, but the others appear randomly to me.
How do I determine what characters grant Vault tokens in Marvel Puzzle Quest when used?
